# 401 while creating customer in quickbooks using php api

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks

I keep getting 401 in spite of using the test keys from the playground app, can someone help on how to resolve this, code works fine on a dev server, as soon as code moved to qa server i created a new QuickBooks account and a new app and now i keep getting a 401

Answer (score 0):

Just moving code from one server to another is a guaranteed way to break anything OAuth related.

You would need to *at least*:

- Move the code
- Change the OAuth URLs in Intuit's control panel to point to the new server
- Change the OAuth URLs in your code
- Clear any stored OAuth access tokens from your database (if you moved the data in the database to the new server as well)
- Reconnect to QuickBooks, via the [Connect to QuickBooks] button

Additional notes:

- Why are you using test keys from Intuit's playground app? Create your own app, and use your own keys.
- If you created a new app, you'll also need to swap our your OAuth consumer key, OAuth consumer secret, and App token in your code.
- Be aware that if your app is in DEVELOPMENT mode, then you can only connect to DEVELOPMENT QuickBooks accounts. If you created a LIVE QuickBooks account, you can only connect to it with PRODUCTION/LIVE app credentials (e.g. you need to PUBLISH your app).

Since you didn't post:

- Your code
- Screenshots of the credentials from Intuit's control panel (assuming they are dev/sandbox and thus safe to post)
- Any of the HTTP requests/responses you're sending/receiving

We won't be able to really help you much further.